# How do I send authenticated https requests using Python?

Tags: python, https, http-authentication

What is the equivalent Python to the following `curl` command?

```
curl https://www.streak.com/api/v1/boxes/{Keyhere}/  -u passwordhere:
```

I tried this but I get 400 errors:

```
requests.get('https://www.streak.com/api/v1/boxes/{Key}/threads -u PASSWORD:', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('USER', 'pass'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of authentication is very common and the requests documentation [covers](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication) it.

```
requests.get('https://www.streak.com/api/v1/boxes/{Key}/threads', auth=(YOUR_API_KEY, ''))
```

---

You need to remove the `-u PASSWORD:` from your destination.

An alternative is to use the [`streak_client`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/streak_client/) package on PiPY or [GitHub](https://github.com/mehmetg/streak_client)

Comment: @ZinouAyachi, I've updated my answer and added an alternative package to use instead of rolling your own.

Comment: Thank you Andy. I have already tried this package but could not get anywhere, the first thing is an error when importing
ImportError: cannot import name 'StreakClient', the second is the absence of documentation..

Comment: Are you behind a proxy of some kind? I just created a key and tried both methods I mentioned without problems.

Comment: No proxy. ( note: if i use the direct curl commands on cmd i get results) this is very frustrating. Thanks for the help